# Easiest way to manage backup of mongoDB on AWS

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services

Right now I'm using `Jenkins` to backup my `mongoDB` in `s3`.
I want to move the job from `Jenkins` to some AWS service.
I want to get some runtime error if it takes more than some threshold that I have, and I'm debating which service to use, does anyone have some suggestions?

What is the best practice?
(My `MongoDB` is pretty big (Backup takes around 5 hours) so just Lambda will not do the job.)

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for AWS managed solution then have a look at [DocumentDB](https://aws.amazon.com/documentdb/). You can run Mongo on AWS DocumentDB and the backup is quite easy there. It stores the backup on s3 by default and you can define the backup job time window which suits your need.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/backup_restore.html